# Do we cancel units on division?

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis

In acceleration, we divide distance/time by time, for example, $50\ \mathrm{m/s} ÷ 5\ \mathrm s = 50\ \mathrm{m/s^2}$. But if we divide $10\ \mathrm{m/s} ÷ 10\ \mathrm{m/s^2}$, the result is 1 second. Why is that so? With acceleration, we add $\mathrm s$ to $\mathrm s$ resulting in $\mathrm s^2$. But, in my second example, why is it cancelled?

Answer (score 9):

It's really just the rules of how fractions work:

$$\frac{m}{s} \div s = \frac{m}{s} \times \frac{1}{s} = \frac{m}{s^2}$$

but

$$\frac{m}{s} \div \frac{m}{s^2} = \frac{m}{s} \times \frac{s^2}{m} = s$$

Comment: I don't think this is sufficient as an answer, since those rules are made for numbers and it is not obvious that you can do the same with units. Perhaps there is some useful information in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis

Comment: I think that it is a perfect answer for the question as asked.  But I do agree that there are deeper questions.  The "/" in 3/4 does not have the same meaning as it does in 3m/4s.   This is where many early learners get lost in math, and become math-phobic.

Comment: @D.Ennis I disagree that it doesn't have the same meaning.  The difference being that a fraction of two unitless numbers can be expressed in ways that a fraction of two numbers with units cannot.

Comment: @JMac I would be interested to know exactly what that same meaning is.  It's a deeper subject than many realize.  I have an associate , Rob MacDuff,  who is a physics education researcher at ASU.   If you're interested, you may want to Google him.  To oversimplify a bit, he discovered that most people have a gap in understanding between number and quantity.

Comment: @D.Ennis I'm not saying that 3/4 is the same expression as 3m/4s.  The way I see it in both cases you are still expressing the ratio though.  I understand that quantities and numbers are different; but I don't see how the "/" operator acts any different on the level we're discussing it.  Does it not signify that we are concerned with the ratio of the two regardless?

Comment: @JMac Yes, and we can treat those ratios the same way arithmetically, but they have different meanings.  To paraphrase Arnold Arons in "Teaching Introductory Physics," the ratio 3/4 means divide to get the size of the number when 3 is divided into 4 parts.  The ratio 3kg/4kg means divide to find how the mass of one object compares to that of another.  The ratio 3m/4s means that 3m *are associated* with 4s, and it can't be resolved by division except to reduce it to 0.75 m/s.

Comment: @D.Ennis So that seems to agree with what I'm saying.  The "/" is not what has a non-standard meaning.  It still functions to represent a ratio.  The ratio of 2 numbers just holds a different significance than the ratio between 2 quantities (which makes sense, numbers lack the extra degree of information that quantities have).  I consider that a characteristic of the quantities, not of the "/" symbol.

Comment: @JMac No.  In 3/4, "/" means *divide* 3 into 4 parts.  In m/s, "/" means 1m *is associated with* 1s.  You can't divide m into s parts.

Comment: @D.Ennis Are you sure that the "/" operator requires that definition?  I've interpreted it as "3÷4" is "divide 3 into 4 parts" while "3/4" is "three-fourths" or "3 per 4", which can be expressed equivalently as "0.75" or "3 divided into 4 parts", which can not be done in the same fashion if there are also units.  I guess that would depend more on formal definitions of the "/" operator, but I feel like that is not the exact same definition as  ÷.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52366/discussion-between-d-ennis-and-jmac).

Answer (score 2):

velocity$(\frac{m}{s})$ / time $(s)$ = acceleration $(\frac{m}{s^2})$

time $(s)$ = $\frac{velocity (\frac{m}{s})}{ acceleration (\frac{m}{s^2})}$.

Now look at the definition of acceleration. Suppose a body has an acceleration of 2$\frac{m}{s^2}$ then it means that the body attains a additional velocity of 2$\frac{m}{s}$ in 1 second, or in other words, for every one second that passes the body gains an extra velocity of 2$\frac{m}{s}$

Now lets say, the velocity of the body is 4$\frac{m}{s}$. So according to the value of acceleration (2 meter per second, per second) the body will attain a velocity of 4$\frac{m}{s}$ after 2 seconds given that its initial velocity is zero.

And thats how this makes sense to me. Hope this helps.

Comment: Missing a number in the second to last paragraph.

Comment: someone edited it wrong